# Logged in to vi, made changes, forgot to sudo first - now what

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, vi

I made lengthy changes to a configuration file on a Ubuntu Linux computer with the vi editor. Unfortunately, I forgot to sudo first, so now I'm in the editor, but can't save my changes because of missing rights. Can I retroactively sudo the user on that terminal, or what would be the best course of action to take?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005/getting-root-permissions-on-a-file-inside-of-vi

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this case, I write the file with `:w /tmp/tmpfile`. Then I go out and move `/tmp/tmpfile` to my old file with sudo rights.

Comment: this is what i end up doing, but i like [wfaulk's answer](http://superuser.com/questions/53733/logged-in-to-vi-made-changes-forgot-to-sudo-first-now-what/53743#53743) .. if i can only remember it the next time i do this! :)

Comment: I hope you ***copy*** the file rather than *moving* it. Moving replaces the file’s mode (permissions) with `vi`’s default (which is probably 666, ANDed with the inverse of your “umask”), replaces the file’s owner with your UID (it was “root”, wasn’t it?), and breaks hard links.

Comment: A couple of issues: (1) If the file is supposed to be confidential, and your “umask” is 22 (rather than 66), this procedure exposes the file’s contents to other users who might be monitoring the `/tmp` directory. (2) If you have truly evil users on your system, they could replace your `/tmp/tmpfile` between when you write it (from `vi`) and when you copy it over the system configuration file that you were editing. It’s safer to put the temporary file into a directory that only you have access to.

Answer (score 40):

From [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005/getting-root-permissions-on-a-file-inside-of-vi):

```
:w !sudo tee %
```

I actually find myself using this way to do it more frequently now:

```
:%!sudo tee %
```

I think it's a little more intuitive, as I know what `:%!` does, whereas I don't have a visceral understanding of `:w !`.  Also, it's easy to miss the very important space between the `w` and the `!`.

Comment: If it helps your intuition any, remember that `vi` commands can be multiple letters, so there could theoretically be a “`wfoo`” command, so if you want to write to a file called “`foo`”, you must say “`:w foo`”. I.e., you need a space after “`:w`”. As far as “`:w !`” is concerned – you know what “`:!`” is, right? “`:!date`” runs a “`date`” command. So “`:w !xyz`” writes the buffer, but ***to a command*** rather than to a file.

Comment: This should be made the accepted answer as the current existing answer is a rather long work-around whereas this is an immediate solution. OP?

Comment: @Scott thanks for the explanation!
What is tee and `%` though ?

Comment: @CodyBugstein: Hello. (1) Pinging the authors of six-year-old comments often gets you nowhere, as people sometimes leave and never come back.  But I’m chained to my computer; I’ll probably be here forever.  (Or maybe not.) (2) Have you tried doing research?  It should be easy to find information on “tee”.  (`%` may be harder.) (3) OK, I’ll help you out a little.  `tee` is a program that lets you write information to multiple places.  For example, `date | tee cody` will write the current date and time to a file called `cody` … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  and also to the terminal screen.  `date | tee cody > bugstein` will write the current date and time to a file called `cody` and also to a file called `bugstein`. — Do you understand `sudo`?  It lets you run a command with the privileges of another user (typically root).  For example, `ls /root` will generally fail, because you don’t have access to `/root`.  But `sudo ls /root` will work. — An unfortunate side-effect of the way Unix works is that `sudo ls /root > /root/cody` will fail, because you don’t have access to `/root`, and so you can’t write to `/root/cody`. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  People have used the trick of saying ``| sudo tee /root/cody`` instead of ``> /root/cody`` to write to a file that you don’t have access to.  (4) Do you understand `!` in `vi`?  It lets you run a shell command from within `vi`.  (This is called a “shell escape”.)  For example, `:!date` will show you the current date and time, and `:w !wc` will pipe your edit buffer into `wc`.  Well, in a shell escape, `%` stands for the name of the current file.  So, if you’re editing a file called `cody`, then `ls -l %` does `ls -l cody`.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (5) So, bottom line, `:w !sudo tee %` will do `:w !sudo tee cody`, which will let you write the edit buffer to the `cody` file even if you don’t have write access to it.

Comment: wow thanks for the answer ! I did look up tee, but had trouble understanding how it worked, especially in this context. Don't ever let anyone unchain you from that computer !

Answer (score -2):

Couldn't you open another terminal and temporarily change the file's access rights?

Comment: This is a bad idea. Probably wont ever be a big security problem, but it could be, and there's better and simpler solutions (like writing to a temporary file, or better, the `:w !sudo tee % solution` wfaulk posted